# How to set validation for drop down in Excel using c# ClosedXML using method List(String list, Boolean inCellDropdown)

Tags: c#, .net, excel, closedxml

Hi All I am trying to create a dropdown list for a column in my excel using ClosedXML library. I am able to create it successfully using the below code.

```
      using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
      {
        wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);
        wb.Worksheets.Add(dt2);
        var worksheet2 = wb.Worksheet(2);
        //wb.Worksheet(1).Column(11).SetDataValidation().List("one,two,three", true); This does not work fine
        wb.Worksheet(1).Column(11).SetDataValidation().List(worksheet2.Range("A2:A12"), true);// Works fine
        wb.Worksheet(1).Column(11).SetDataValidation().IgnoreBlanks = true;
        wb.Worksheet(1).Column(11).SetDataValidation().InCellDropdown = true;
        wb.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
        wb.Style.Font.Bold = true;
        wb.SaveAs(targetFile);
      }
```

But I want to do the same thing with another overloaded method of List in SetDataValidation() but that is creating the excel but when I am trying to open it, it says its corrupted. Could you please help me understand why the other overloaded method is not working.

The method in question is [public void List(String list, Boolean inCellDropdown)](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/blob/develop/ClosedXML/Excel/DataValidation/XLDataValidation.cs#L210). According to the [Data Validation wiki page](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Data-Validation) using a string list is possible :

```
//Pass a string in this format: "Option1,Option2,Option3"
var options = new List<string>{"Option1","Option2","Option3"};
var validOptions = $"\"{String.Join(",", options)}\"";
ws.Cell(1,1).DataValidation.List(validOptions, true);
```

Comment: What other overloaded method? You can't ask about problems with code you haven't posted. The current code can be cleaned up a lot too - there's no reason to make the same calls repeatedly. Just store the worksheets, column and probably the result of `SetDataValidation()` in variables and reuse them. This avoids CPU waste and makes debugging and troubleshooting a lot easier too

Comment: I have mentioned the other overloaded method in comment. You can refer te sixth line of code.

Comment: That's a commented out line. It doesn't mean that method exists, or that if it does, it works the way you think. This doesn't show the method's signature. Have you checked CloseXML's documentation? Is there another method? What are its parameters? Any links?

Comment: Here is link of source code where you can see that commented method exists. I commented it just to show which code works and the one which does not. sorry for the confusion. https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/blob/develop/ClosedXML/Excel/DataValidation/XLDataValidation.cs

Comment: Put that in the *question itself* and make it clear what you want to call. I've found that method by googling already. I shouldn't have to do that. Anyone else that reads looking into that question shouldn't have to, either. Quite simply, by the time people find what you're talking about, they may no longer have time to answer. I no longer can

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Data Validation](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Data-Validation) wiki page, the list list must include the double quotes.

In the doc example :

```
var options = new List<string>{"Option1","Option2","Option3"};
var validOptions = $"\"{String.Join(",", options)}\"";
ws.Cell(1,1).DataValidation.List(validOptions, true);
```

`validOptions` contains :

```
"Option1,Option2,Option3"`
```

Your own code should change to :

```
.List("\"one,two,three\"", true);
```

Comment: Thank you it worked also got to know about wiki page on git repo which I wasn't aware till now.

Answer (score 3):

> Because official document has few examples, so I post some detail
> examples here to show  how to add dropdown list into excel.

```
        //set data validation, dropdown list
        // if we want list abcd in a cell, we should add ""
        var validateList = "\"A,B,C,D\"";

        //1.use column index
        worksheet.Column(3).SetDataValidation().List(validateList, true);

         //2.use column name
        worksheet.Column("D").SetDataValidation().List(validateList, true);

        //3.use column range
        worksheet.Range("E1:E20").SetDataValidation().List(validateList, true);
```

[closedxml/wiki/Data-Validation](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki/Data-Validation)

Comment: Although that may answer the question, please consider adding some explanation.

Comment: Consider adding some commentary on how your code example works compared to the code included in the question.